# Does tracemalloc removes freed memory from its recent snapshot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am trying to debug a Python with Flask application with memory growth over time.

I a understand that tracemalloc tracks allocated memory by Python, and it shows me the backtrace of that memory being allocated in my program in each snapshot.

My question is if the recent snapshot shows historical data of the memory allocated or if it shows the memory allocated but wasn't freed.

I took a tracemalloc snapshot after memory was increased in my program

Answer (score 0):

Based on a test I did, it looks like `tracemalloc` doesn't track freed memory.

```
import tracemalloc
import gc
tracemalloc.start(1)
y = None

def dump_tracemalloc_snapshot():
        gc.collect()
        snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
        stats = snapshot.statistics('traceback')
        for stat in stats[:3]:
            print("%s memory blocks: %.1f KiB" % (stat.count, stat.size / 1024))

            for line in stat.traceback.format():
                print(line)

        print('\n\n')        


def allocate_memory():
    global y
    x = []
    for i in range(100000):
        x.append(f"AAA{i}")
    y = x


if __name__=="__main__":
    allocate_memory()
    
    dump_tracemalloc_snapshot()
    del y 
    dump_tracemalloc_snapshot()
```

Output:

```
100001 memory blocks: 6337.7 KiB
  File "/Users/jafar.atili/Code/tracemalloc_parser/file.py", line 23
    x.append(f"AAA{i}")
1 memory blocks: 0.1 KiB
  File "/Users/jafar.atili/Code/tracemalloc_parser/file.py", line 19
    def allocate_memory():
1 memory blocks: 0.1 KiB
  File "/Users/jafar.atili/Code/tracemalloc_parser/file.py", line 6
    def dump_tracemalloc_snapshot():



26 memory blocks: 2.1 KiB
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/linecache.py", line 137
    lines = fp.readlines()
2 memory blocks: 0.2 KiB
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/linecache.py", line 143
    cache[filename] = size, mtime, lines, fullname
1 memory blocks: 0.1 KiB
  File "/Users/jafar.atili/Code/tracemalloc_parser/file.py", line 19
    def allocate_memory():
```